# warning: PageContainer(...): React component classes must extend React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, css-transitions

I am trying to use [react-page-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-page-transitions) and I am getting this warning:

> "PageContainer(...): React component classes must extend React.Component."

my code looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import firebase_det from '../../details_data/firebase';

var firebase = require('firebase');
var AppActions = require('../../Action/AppActions');
var AppStore = require('../../Stores/AppStore');
import Formsy from 'formsy-react';
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
import MyOwnInput from '../Testing/MyOwnInput';
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');
var PageContainer = require('react-page-transitions');

class Signup extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PageContainer>
        <div> </div>
      </PageContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From React v0.14 on, components implemented as ES6 classes *without* extending `React.Component` are deprecated. They should extend `React.Component` (just like the warning says):

```
class Component extends React.Component {

}
```

From the [official blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning):

> ES6 component classes must now extend React.Component in order to enable stateless function components. The [ES3 module pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#other-languages) will continue to work.

From the github repository I see that react-page-transition is implemented as

```
var PageContainer = React.createClass({
})
```

So there is the problem

To solve it what you can do it is that once you have done npm install react-page-transition, just go to the node_modules and edit the code using ES6 structure and it will work.

EDIT

Okay so to get around it just create a new file PageContainer.js and write the following code in it

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';

export default class PageContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state =  {
            mounted: false,
            startStyles: {
                'translateX': '100%'
            },
            endStyles: {
                'translateX': 0
            },
            easing: 'swing',
            duration: 400,
            callback: function() {

            }
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState(this.props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var me = this;

        // Hook styles
        for (var key in this.state.startStyles) {
            Velocity.hook(this.getDOMNode(), key, this.state.startStyles[key]);
        }

        this.setState({ mounted: true });
        this.getDOMNode().style.display = 'block';

        var options = {
            duration: this.state.duration,
            easing: this.state.easing,
            complete: function () {
                me.getDOMNode().classList.add('loaded-page');
                me.state.callback();
            }
        };

        Velocity(this.getDOMNode(),
            this.state.endStyles,
            options
        );
    },
    render() {
        var child;
        var classString = 'page-content ' + this.props.className;
        if(this.state.mounted){
            child = (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
        }
        return (
            <section className="page-content" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                {child}
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

and import this as

```
import PageContainer from './path/to/PageContainer'
```

also you will need to do

```
npm install -S velocity-animate
```

I think this will solve the problem. Let me know I haven't tested it.

Comment: in node_modules you will see PageContainer. Go inside it its src folder and into index.js. There change to class PageContainer extends React.Component and for getInitialState replace it with a constructor

Comment: man i am using this"https://github.com/srn/react-webpack-boilerplate" and i can find a file in this.. can you guide me by coming on my pc through teamviewer. i will be thankful to you man.

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: I dont have teamviewer on my laptop.

Comment: i can't find a file*******

Comment: can you please install it.. or on skype?? what you say?

Comment: Just give my edit a try. If it fails we can work on skype

Comment: i allready give a try man... its not working.. please give me your skype details or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121994/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-m03a3a17).

Answer (score 0):

you need to choose either `import` your packages or using `var` to require the modules, as in this case `react-page-transitions` doesn't come up with native es6 modules, you better try like below or you can change the code of
`react-page-transitions`

```
var React = require('react');
var PageContainer = require('react-page-transitions');

var Signup = React.createClass({

   //your code goes here

});
```

EDIT: just saw it from their github repos their are number of people complaining about it you can check it from the below url,

https://github.com/jaing/react-page-transitions/issues/4

so to use  `react-page-transitions` you have to update some code

or you can try `react-motion` check it from the below url,

https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion